# Existe uma ferramenta para fazer manuais html de fácil atualização?

Tags: php, html

Gostaria de saber se existe um ferramenta para fazer manuais tipo em HTML de fácil atualização e que desse pra customizar 100%.

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Manuais da sua aplicação? Ou estás a criar manuais para qualquer produto? Se for a primeira opção, o [phpDocumentor](https://www.phpdoc.org) será teu amigo.

Answer (score 7):

Além das opções informadas por Lacobus:  [phpDocumentor](https://www.phpdoc.org/) ou o [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl) ...  existem o [ApiGen](http://www.apigen.org/), o [phpDox](http://phpdox.de/), o [phpXRef](http://phpxref.sourceforge.net/), o [PHPDoctor](http://www.peej.co.uk/phpdoctor/), o [PHPSimpleDoc](http://phpsimpledoc.tig12.net/) e outros.

O phpDocumentor possui templates.
O phpdox utiliza estilos CSS que facilitam a personalização.

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 6):

Além dos já citados [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) e [phpDocumentor](https://www.phpdoc.org/).
Podemos incluir na lista:

[Dexy](http://www.dexy.it/)
[Apiary](https://apiary.io/products) (pago)
[Docco](https://jashkenas.github.io/docco/) (coffeeScript)
[Daux](http://daux.io/index) (muito bom)
[Natural Docs](http://www.naturaldocs.org/)
[HelpNDoc](http://www.helpndoc.com/)

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 5):

Atualmente, existem novas propostas como o [Doclets](https://doclets.io/) e o [DAUX](http://daux.io/), ferramentas na nuvem que facilitam, e muito, a geração de manuais e documentação.

Answer (score 4):

Que tal o [phpDocumentor](https://www.phpdoc.org/) ou o [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl) ?

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, vlw!

Answer (score 3):

Aqui na empresa estamos usando o [Gitbook](https://www.gitbook.com/), ótima ferramenta de manual, usando **MARKDOWN**, referências a páginas e arquivos externos funciona com versionamento.
Vale muito a pena.